# Docker COPY and keep directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Need to copy multiple directories in my Dockerfile. Currently, I'm doing:

```
COPY dir1 /opt/dir1
COPY dir2 /opt/dir2
COPY dir3 /opt/dir3
```

I would prefer to consolidate those into one single statement, specifying all the sources in one go. However, this way the **contents** are copied, and I lose the `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3` structure:

```
COPY dir1 dir2 dir3 /opt/
```

Same in this case:

```
COPY dir1/ dir2/ dir3/ /opt/
```

Is there some way to achieve this with one line?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715224/copy-multiple-directories-with-one-command and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256386/how-to-copy-multiple-files-in-one-layer-using-a-dockerfile

Comment: @TarunLalwani second link is not a copy. In docerfile copy there is a nightmare difference between file and folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider `ADD` instead of `COPY`: see [Dockerfile `ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)

> If `<src>` is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory.

That means you can wrap your docker build step into a script which would first `tar -cvf dirs.tar dir1 dir2 dir3`

Your Dockerfile can then `ADD dirs.tar`: you will find your folders in your image.

See also [Dockerfile Best Practices: `ADD` or `COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy).

Comment: Admittedly, I had hoped for something simpler, but: Interesting idea, thank you!

Comment: @qqilihq another alternative would be for your local folders to be in a common parent folder, ready to be `COPY`'ed, and once copied, moved by `RUN mv` commands in the Dockerfile to their final place.

Comment: @VonC this solution is better from all perspectives.