# Why Docker copies directory contents but not the directory itself?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I thought using `COPY` (or `ADD`) in `Dockerfile` cannot really go wrong but guess I don't know life.

So I have this trivial `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY 123 789 ./
```

with directory structure in my project as:

```
.
├── 123
│   └── 456
├── 789
└── Dockerfile
```

After building this, to my surprise I don't get directories `123` and `789` but only directory `456`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it image:tag ls -a /app/
.    ..   456
```

Why is that? Can I make it so that I copy the desired directories?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do If you want to copy a folder's contents to a folder, try e.g. COPY 123 /123. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: Hah! That works. Thanks. You might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37715522/596285